# Strategy for avoiding name conflicts when copying user-selected files?

Tags: algorithm, desktop-application

I'm developing a desktop app in `Electron' which allows the "non-pro" user to import (copy) images from their local drive into a project directory which they created earlier. Through the platform dialog (OSX or Windows), the user can select single or multiple images, or single or multiple directories, which could also include sub-directories.

I know how to handle the coding but I am stumped on a strategy to avoid naming conflicts, particularly as images may be coming from camera files which use a simple naming scheme, with batch imports from different camera sessions having the same names.

For a simple example, a user could pick both the "DCIM" directories below, or make selections from within each of the directories of files with the same name.

This is likely a very common programming issue and there must be some solutions which people smarter than me have come up with – but I don't know what this problem is called, in order to search for them.

[image]

Comment: Does the user even care about names after the images are imported? And do you really need to make copies (images are huge), or can the files stay where they are?

Comment: @user3386109 - I need to make copies because the "project" they create could get moved to different machines, etc. I am wondering about if changing the original file name to some naming scheme I control would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've seen is to look for a naming conflict, and then append something to the name of the thing being imported, before the ending.  So you'll see files named `foo.txt`, `foo-001.txt`, `foo-002.txt`, and so on.

If you expect a great many conflicts, the appended text should be random, instead of sequential.  That's because it takes 51 duplicate checks before settling on `foo-050.txt` but only 2.0000214334705... before settling on `foo-kyc.txt`.  The performance difference can be quite noticeable after many conflicts for many files.